# difference between 'natural full outer join' and 'full outer join'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have read W3 school notes and database system concepts book but the difference between natural full outer join and full outer join still seems vague. So far my understanding is that natural join will join naturally on the matching column values where in full outer join we must explicitly state `on` clause. Should we? Or I am making some mistakes in my understanding?

Comment: I am with Gordon Linoff: simply forget that natural joins exist. Imagine you have a working query and then one day someone adds a column to one of the tables with the same name as an existing column in a joined table (happens easily with columns names such as `name`, `text`, `image`, `description`, `status`, etc.). Then suddenly your query would return incorrect results although the query itself was never changed.

Comment: With full outer joins it is often convenient to use `USING` instead of `ON` btw (e.g. `select x, a.y, b.z from a full outer join b using (x)` rather than `select coalesce(a.x,b.x) as x, a.y, b.z from a full outer join b on a.x = b.x`). That goes especially for queries with more than one outer join on the same column(s).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Natural join` is basically an abomination.  Don't use it.

The problem is that `natural join` uses the *names* of columns in the tables to define the `join` relationship.  This makes it hard to understand queries, because you don't know what the relationships are.  Worse, `natural join` doesn't even use *declared* foreign key relationships.

Use `using` or `on` instead.

As for the difference between `natural full outer join` and `full outer join`.  They both are `full outer join`.  In the latter, you explicitly define the keys for the `join` condition.  In the former, the database engine chooses the keys based on common names between the tables.

Comment: There might be some use cases for it: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/07/impress-your-coworkers-with-a-sql-natural-full-outer-join/

Comment: @Chef1075 . . . Let's just say that I pretty much disagree with everything that post says.  There is nothing "natural" about a "natural join".  And the fact that it doesn't recognize properly declared foreign key relationships means that it never should have been included in the language.